# Are any Ubuntu (Linux) vulnerabilities in media applications?

Tags: security, privileges

Ubuntu (Linux)  has a solid system that permits and requires root privileges to modify the system.

However; if an installed application eg. VLC, audacious, some image viewer installed from the software center has a vulnerability, and these applications play a file with an embedded malicious code or maybe an executable does exploits vulnerabilities in the application that was already running with administrator privileges (VLC, audacious etc ...).

Could this compromise the system?

Comment: To clarify; a Technique called "Steganography" could be used to conceal/embed a file into another (mostly a malicious file into an normal looking image, document...etc) so that running the container file, executes the malicious in the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is entirely plausible. The simple way to prevent this is to adhere to the principle of least privilege and to only run programs with elevated permissions only when it's required. For example, you would need to do this for managing user and group accounts, but this should never be done for running media apps such as VLC.